# tx_news and multi-language

Tags: typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

I'm using Typo3 6.2 and EXT tx_news in a multilingual installation (L=0 German, L=1 English, L=2 Italian, with more to come). Everything works fine if I make a newsrecord in standard-language and translate it via localization to the other languages.

Here the problem:
Some news should only be in one specific language, not necessarily the standard language.

But if I create a newsrecord telling it should be Italian for example, no pictures are shown in the FE, neither in list- nor in detail-view. The pics are in the record, marked as "Show at list-view" (maybe wrong translated, I'm using the BE in German), but in the outputted code, the news-image-wrap is empty:

```
<div class="news-img-wrap"> </div> == §0
```

Would be very pleased to get help here!

Comment: Update: If I go to the newsrecord AGAIN, delete the pictures -> safe -> upload the pictures again -> safe: the pictures are shown in detail-view, but still not in list-view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a problem of wrap.
It sounds like a problem of translation handling. dio you use translation or only multilanguage?
You might need a record in default-language with the option not to be shown but with the images for *all* languages.

Comment: I don't use translation, just multi-lang (EXT sr_language_menu). I already tried to set up a record in default-lang (bulb off) and localized the wanted language (bulb on) but in FE it sais "No news available".

With a parent record in wanted language, the news gets shown up, but without pictures